# Dependency injection in my singleton class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, singleton, autowired

Let's say I have interface Bar:

```
public interface Bar {

    void lengthyOperation ();

}
```

and it's implementation Foo:

```
@Service
public class Foo implements Bar {

    void lengthyOperation () {

        // lengthy operation implementation

    }

}
```

I also have a singleton class called MyClass:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    @Autowired private final Bar bar;

    private final Thread thread;
    private static MyClass instance;

    private MyClass () {

        thread = new Thread (this);
        thread.start();

    }

    public static MyClass getInstance () {

        if (instance == null) instance = new MyClass();
        return instance;

    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            bar.lengthyOperation();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

        }

    }

}
```

How can I inject Bar into MyClass using @Autowired annotation (or any other way if possible)? I tried with @Autowired private final Bar bar; but it's always null;

If that can't be achieved, is there a way to prevent calling @Autowired constructor twice? If you don't know what I mean let me show you. This code:

```
@Controller
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    private final Bar bar;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass (Bar bar) {

        this.bar = bar;
        thread = new Thread (this);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("New thread...");

        while (true) {

            bar.lengthyOperation();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

        }

    }

}
```

would print out "New thread..." two times in console.
Maybe (probably) there is more gracious way of doing this, but I don't know about it... Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

**EDIT #1** dimoniy asked how I make instance of my class. Basically, instance of MyClass has to be created on WebApp startup, so I used this code:

```
@Component
public class StartMyClass implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent e) {
        MyClass.getInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create your instance of `MyClass`?
The @Autowired does not work because your `MyClass` instance is not managed by Spring. You need to create `MyClass` instance in your Java/XML spring configuration or annotate it with `@Component` annotation and make sure that MyClass's package is scannable by spring.
Your annotation with `@Controller` is not correct since your class is clearly not a controller...

For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MiscConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public MyClass myClass() {
      return new MyClass();//Will be created/managed by Spring, @Autowired will work
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. I updated my question to show how I make instance of MyClass. Since I'm currently away from my computer, I can't test if it works, but I will check your reply as an answer to my question if it works. Cheers.

Comment: @Z0K4 yes, I've checked the code and as written the MyClass instance will not be managed by Spring and autowiring will not work. Just do it the way I shown in my example and it should work. You can also remove the getInstance() thing from your class since all the classes are singletons in spring by default. On the side note: you might want to use thread pool to manage your threads instead of creating threads by yourself.